# Firemonkey ColorDialog

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm searching for an easy way to make the user select a color, in VCL I've always used the TColorDialog (VCL.Dialogs), but there either is no equivalent in FMX or I'm just not able to find it.

I could obviousely make my own color dialog using the existing components, but I thought there might be an easier & more elegant solution. I also thought about directly using Windows ChooseColor, but I'd need some sample code on how to wrap that; also this would not translate to Mac which is not an immediate issue but might impose problems later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a cross-platform solution you can build you own dialog using the FMX components like TColorPanel, TColorPicker and so on.  How you are asking about a wrapper for the Windows ChooseColor Dialog this is a very simple sample [adapted from the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
uses
 System.UIConsts,
 FMX.Platform.Win,
 Winapi.Windows,
 Winapi.CommDlg;

const
  MaxCustomColors = 16;
type
  TCustomColors = array[0..MaxCustomColors - 1] of Longint;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 cc : TChooseColor;
 acrCustClr: TCustomColors;
 hwnd : THandle;
 rgbCurrent : DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(cc, sizeof(cc), #0);
  cc.lStructSize := sizeof(cc);
  cc.hwndOwner :=  FmxHandleToHWND(Self.Handle);
  cc.lpCustColors := @acrCustClr;
  cc.rgbResult := RGBtoBGR(claYellow);
  cc.Flags := CC_FULLOPEN OR CC_RGBINIT;
  if (ChooseColor(cc))  then
     Rectangle1.Fill.Color:= MakeColor(GetRValue(cc.rgbResult), GetGValue(cc.rgbResult), GetBValue(cc.rgbResult));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, as always. Is there a way to adjust the wrapper to show in the center of my form rather than at (0,0) ?

Comment: You must get the handle to the dialog and then use the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.